# How to iterate through Java collection in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript

I'm trying to do scripting with Javascript in a Java program. I haven't found a way to iterate through a Java collection in Javascript. If I call the iterator() method for the collection, I get the method names instead of the elements.

Here's a sample code:

```
function getValue(row, components) {
    var apartment = components.get(0);
    var rooms = apartment.getRooms();
    for (var room in rooms.iterator()) {
        println(room);
    }
    return rooms.toString();
}
```

The apartment.getRooms() returns a collection of rooms. When I study the value returned by this function, I know that its content are correct, but the values that get printed are the method names.

I invoke the Javascript from my Java program like this:

```
getInvocable().invokeFunction("getValue", row, components);
```

Comment: Can you show how you invoke javascript from java?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644966/javascript-iterator-class) might help

Comment: Shouldn't he use Struts or something? I think the user is confusing Java and Javascript together? I'm pretty confused just reading his question.

Comment: @TechExchange Why did you edit question? Are you sure collection is not java collection?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov code clearly shows it's JS

Comment: I call javascript as follows:
    getInvocable().invokeFunction("getValue", row, components)

The getInvocable() method loads the javascript and gets the Invocable function from it, but I don't think calling from Java is the problem. The problem is that the iterator of Javascript overrides the iterator of the Java object.

Comment: @user1983702 please post more code. What is `getInvocable()`? What libraries do you use? Edit your question

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov I think OP uses Rhino JS engine

Comment: println(room) prints the keys of the properties contained in the object returned by method rooms.iterator(). Maybe rooms.iterator()[room] (the value instead of key) is what you want? But it's hard to say without seeing more code.

Comment: Please post your output too, it would help a lot in identifying the cause of your problem

Comment: How has this mess got four upvotes?

Answer (score 7):

It seems that if I do the iteration as follows:

```
function getValue(row, components) {
    var apartment = components.get(0);
    var rooms = apartment.getRelated();
    for (var iterator = rooms.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        var room = iterator.next();
        println(room);
    }
    return rooms.toString();
}
```

It works.

Comment: if that worked you could probably try `for (var room in rooms)` as well

Comment: Hm. Yes. As I know javascript's `for in` loop iterates through object properties. methods are also properties - then why you getting list of methods. I'm not sure `for in` loop works well with java collections.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov i was guessing, without knowing anything about the environment. What's treaten as properties when you're dealing with java objects in js? Everything? java properties with get/set? What about Maps?

Comment: @soulcheck I checked and it seems it iterates through public methods and properties. For map it returned only all public methods without any data that contained in private properties.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov ah, ok. What env is that? rhino?

Comment: @soulcheck yes. I didn't know that oracle JVM goes with included rhino engine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649519/jvm-missing-rhino

Answer (score 4):

To use `for in` you will have to convert it [to an array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29) first:

```
Collection<String> coll = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");

String script = "var arr = coll.toArray();\n"
    + "for(var idx in arr) println(arr[idx]);\n";

ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager()
    .getEngineByName("ECMAScript");
engine.getContext().setAttribute("coll", coll, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
engine.eval(script);
```

Otherwise you will iterate over the object properties.

If you are using Rhino 1.7 or above, you can use its [non-standard iterator support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators):

```
for (i in Iterator(coll)) print(i);
```